# Semi-Complicated recurrence relation to be solved via generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

If $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence such that $a_0=3$ and for all $n \ge 1$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}a_{n-2k+1}=na_n
\end{equation}
, use generating functions to find an explicit formula for $a_n$.

So far I've been swimming around in the algebra a bit, and I've gotten

$$A'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} a_{n-2k+1}\right)x^{n-1}$$

But I'm not sure how to get a nice expression in terms of $A(x)$ for the RHS of this equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation hints that the derivative of $A(x)$ may be involved:
$$A'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} a_{n-2k+1}\right)x^{n-1}=A(x)+x^2A(x)+x^4A(x)+
\ldots,$$
and summing the geometric series one obtains the differential equation
$$A'(x)=\frac{A(x)}{1-x^2}.$$
The solution can be obtained by separation of variables:
$$A(x)=C\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}.$$
Since everything is happening for $x$ near $0$, no need to worry about convergence issues.

Comment: Shouldn't the differential equation on line 2 be $A'(x)=\frac{A(x)}{1-x^2}$?

Comment: also I think you made a mistake with the index here: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} a_{n-2k+1}\right)x^{n-1}=A(x)+x^2A(x)+x^4A(x)+
\ldots,$ just that the outer sum should begin at 1 instead of zero.

Comment: You are right, fixed the typos. About the last equality, I'll admit it is harder to spell it out. I wrote a few terms and convinced myself :)

Comment: I wrote out some terms and convinced myself as well!

Comment: do you have any idea how to find the coefficient of $x^n$ after this? I deduced that the constant is $3$. So we have $A(x)=3\sqrt(\frac{|x+1|}{|x-1|})$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to obtain the differential equation:
\begin{align}
A'(x) 
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} a_{n-2k+1}\right)x^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2k-2} \sum_{n=2k-1}^\infty a_{n-2k+1} x^{n-2k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2k-2} A(x) \\
&= A(x) \sum_{k=1}^\infty (x^2)^{k-1} \\
&= \frac{A(x)}{1-x^2} \\
\end{align}